# Convert forEach in Java to map collect

Tags: java

I have nested map called aMap for which key is a string and value is another map (called y). This y contains strings as key and value. I want to process the values in the nested map and aggregate some of the keys inside y according to some logic (basically I am reducing the number of keys in y). I am able to run my logic using forEach but I need to convert the following using map and collect in Java 8. The problem is I am not sure what to write inside the collect function.

The for each code:

```
aMap.forEach(
      (x, y) -> {
        Set<String> remove = new HashSet<>();
        Map<String, Double> add = new HashMap<>();

        y.forEach(
            (key, value) -> {
              String z = key;
              long b = 0;
              try {
                b = some_conversion_on_z()
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.error("Failed to convert", e);
              }
              if (some_condition_on_b) {
                String d = some_conversion_on_z()
                Double currCount = value;
                Double prevCount = y.get(d);
                if (prevCount == null) {
                  prevCount = 0.0;
                  add.put(d, prevCount + currCount);
                } else {
                  y.put(d, prevCount + currCount);
                  remove.add(z);
                }
              }
            });
        y.keySet().removeAll(remove);
        y.putAll(add);
      });
```

The map-collect that I am trying:

```
aMap.entrySet()
.map(x -> x.getValue())
.map(y -> y.getKey())
.filter(some_condition_on_y)
.collect(?)
```

Comment: This doesn't look especially streamable.  I'd convert it to a straight loop, honestly.

Comment: So,  there is no better way to write this?

Comment: Sure there is: use a normal for-each loop on y.entries(), and e.g. use setValue instead of a put.